# Unity и Python скрипты

Tags: python, unity3d

У меня есть вопрос! Можно ли каким то образом писать скрипты для игры на Unity? Если да, то каким?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно писать скрипты для Unity на Python

Вот ссылка на офиц. сайт Unity об этом
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@2.0/manual/

*Потенциальные преимущества использования Python в вашем проекте Unity включают:*

*Автоматизация сборки сцены и последовательности в контексте использования Unity в качестве средства визуализации в реальном времени.*

*Автоматизация трудоемких задач, таких как дублирование или изменение большого количества активов.*

*Создание пользовательских инструментов редактора, которые могут использовать сложные элементы пользовательского интерфейса и взаимодействовать с другими наборами DCC.*

P.s. Но как я понял, он всё такие не предназначен как основной язык для написания игры ( как C# и JS)